# How/when to close MongoDB connection

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm writing some Go code to get an item from a mongdb.
Here is my code:

```
// GetAllMovies retrieves all movies from the MongoDB
func GetAllMovies() ([]*Movie, error) {
    var movies []*Movie

    client, ctx, cancel := getConnection()
    // defer the execution of code to when the function is exited --> avoid memory leak
    defer cancel()
    defer client.Disconnect(ctx)

    // movies database
    db := client.Database("movies")
    // get movies collection
    collection := db.Collection("movies")
    // put results from movies collection in result cursor
    cursor, err := collection.Find(ctx, bson.D{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // close the cursor once finished (necessary?)
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)

    // iterate the cursor and decodes each document into movies (interface)
    // this method will close the cursor after retrieving all documents
    err = cursor.All(ctx, &movies)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed marshalling %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return movies, nil
}
```

I checked some docs and some other resources to become this. So I have a few questions about it:

Should I run both? What's the main difference?:

```
defer cancel()
defer client.Disconnect(ctx)
```

And should I use:

```
defer cursor.Close(ctx)
```

Because `cursor.All` [will close the cursor after retrieving all documents](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#example-Cursor-All)

Comment: Normally you connect on application start and close MongoDB connection on app shutdown.

Comment: What Mongo driver are you using? What does `getConnection` do? What executes `GetAllMovies`?